# Get values in strings.xml

Tags: xamarin, android-resources, arrays

In Xamarin, I have the following in the strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">AutoComplete</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
   <string name="auto_complete">AutoComplete</string>
   <string name="multi_auto_complete">Multi AutoComplete</string>
   <string-array name="list_of_countries">
      <item >USA</item>
      <item >Uk</item>
      <item >Canada</item>
      <item >Australia</item>
      <item >France</item>
      <item >Italy</item>
      <item >China</item>
      <item >Japan</item>
      <item >Spain</item>
      </string-array>

</resources>
```

How can I get the above data into an array?

Here is my current code (that does not work):

```
String[] countries = Resources.GetStringArray (list_of_countries);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] countries = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.list_of_countries);
```

Path to Strings.xml:

```
Resources/values/Strings.xml
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: Build the application.

Comment: There is "Resource.String", but no "Resource.Array", even after building

Comment: @Garry Do you have access to another strings in Strings.xml?

Comment: @Garry Also check the path to the Srtings.xml